# Converting Data object to String in swift returning nil

Tags: ios, swift, string, nsdata

I'm using the following code to convert Data to String in swift. The returned String is nil. Could you please help me identify what is going wrong. Thank you.

```
let dataObject = try RSAUtils.encryptWithRSAPublicKey(str: textToEncrypt!, pubkeyBase64: pubKeyB64)


let dataToString = String(data: dataObject!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) as String!
```

Comment: Very likely `dataObject` is not a valid data as UTF-8. Please show the contents of `dataObject`.

Comment: What is `dataObject`? Please read this, and then edit your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: we need content of dataObject

Comment: @OOPer and @DonMag the code has been updated. `dataObject` is UTF-8 compliant data object retrieved after running rsa encryption. Thank you for responding.

Comment: Is there a way to print the `dataObject` so I could show its contents to you guys. Thank you for your responses.

Comment: The added code cannot be much help, as we do not know anything about your `RSAUtils`. But generally the result data of encryption cannot be interpreted as a UTF-8 string. What do you want to get from the encrypted data?

Comment: Try `print(dataObject! as NSData)`. If it's not too big, show all the result.

Comment: @Abdelahad Darwish I am not the one.

Comment: @Wallace, If Abdelahad Darwish's answer works for you, `dataObject` is **NOT** a UTF-8 compliant data object. You'd better write the right thing to get a right answer sooner.

Comment: @oOPer  he use  RSAUtils lib RSA encryption and decryption with Swift iOS. you can check how it work https://github.com/btnguyen2k/swift-rsautils

Comment: @OOPer apologies for the ignorant answer from my side. I was not aware of it not being UTF-8 compliant data. Sorry man.

Comment: @AbdelahadDarwish, thanks. But many other developers may have their own `RSAUtils`, so, it should have been clarified in the question. And do not care about down-votes too much. I rarely find _it's me_ comments.

Comment: @Wallace, next chance better, please.

Comment: @OOPer  thanks so much

Comment: @AbdelahadDarwish - instead of asking who down-voted your answer, think about *why* someone might have done so. You (currently) have `let let encryptedDataText =` ... what is `let let`? Your code also force-unwraps `dataObject!` which is bad practice (even with the check for nil). Better to show `if let` or `guard let`. And... your answer doesn't really explain anything, unless they are already familiar with RSAUtils lib. So... just a couple reasons why someone *might* have down-voted. (and, as OOPer said, don't worry so much)

Comment: @DonMag , thanks let let fixed , thanks for your notes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this base 64 encryptedData  by RSAUtils lib so use this

```swift
if ( dataObject != nil ) {
    let encryptedDataText = dataObject!.base64EncodedString(options: NSData.Base64EncodingOptions())
    NSLog("Encrypted with pubkey: %@", encryptedDataText)
}
```